# Using the map and lower functions together

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to use `map` with `lower` so that I can convert some string values to numeric ones, but I am getting a syntax error. Can someone help with how this is implemented?

I tried:

```
df['Response'] = df['Response'].apply(lambda x.lower() : x.map({'yes':1.0,'no':0.0,'maybe':0.5}))
```

and:

```
df['Response'] = df['Response'].apply(lambda x :x.lower().map({'yes':1.0,'no':0.0,'maybe':0.5}))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When asking about errors, it is helpful to actually post the errors...

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Response'].str.lower().map({'yes':1.0,'no':0.0,'maybe':0.5})
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I didnt realize that this can be done without lambda!